# How to share data from my app

Tags: android

I am trying to get a behavior similar to youtube app on android. When "Share" is clicked, the phone gives option of "Share this video via" and then all the applications capable of sharing or sending message show up as options (gmail, email, google voice, whatsapp, twitter, textmessage, etc...).

How can I get a similar functionality in my app? I am mainly interested in two of the above - text messaging, and gmail. When the user picks text messaging option the screen to send a new text message will show up and the body will contain a link from my app and users can select. After this point on, I assume everything will be handled by the OS itself.

I am new to the android world and would love example, insight, and direction toward which API docs should I be reading?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get a similar functionality in my app?

Use `ACTION_SEND`:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

> I am mainly interested in two of the above - text messaging, and gmail

Your user may be interested in any available option. Please do not constrain the means by which the user shares the content. Simply make the content available, with a proper MIME type, and let the user what the user wants to.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to share it like text this is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, SOME_TEXT_HERE);
try
{
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with..."));
}
```

you can change your data type.
Good luck
Regards